# Can NOT set the values of NoteProperty, while parsing json in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I can not set the existing values of noteproperties, neither can i edit any one of those.
I am trying to parse a json file with convertfrom-json in powershell and then make use of different noteproperties by editing their values. 
But by every means i try to do that, it responds with an exception.

- FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

However, i've researched my way out identifying the problem. Kindly, check the attached image for reference.
[image: Here is what the problem is]

I've tried editing the value and setting it to $true but to no avail, can any one one help with this, as for how one could set the value of isSettable to True instead of false.

Any help and directions would be highly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Are you able to show us a sample of the json you are working with? What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You cannot modify them thru `Chars` property (indexer).

Comment: Thank you guys, i was able to fix the problem, by using 
New-itemproperty -name ${bla} -value ${bla} -force

-force was the key, to overwrite the existing noteproperty that that json file object had

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and concern, Really Appreciate it.